# Allow user to delete records he does not own

Tags: profile, permission-sets, userrecordaccess

I want to allow a user to delete all Jobs(custom object) even ones he doesn't own.Do I need to create a permission set.

Please help!!

Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user needs "Modify All" for that specific custom object. You may either add it to their profile, which would affect all users with that profile, or you can create a permission set, which would apply just to that one user when applied to the user. It really depends on how you want to manage your profiles.

Comment: If  I create a permission set and under Object Settings->under Jobs->I need to click on Modify all checkbox coz I need to give access to particular user only Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that'd be just fine. Note that some additional permissions will be required too. The system will automatically select them for you.

Comment: Hi @kunalgupta, thanks are also expressed by marking as accepted and or giving an upvote - it makes everyone happy.

Comment: typo: `Modify All` permission on the object v. `Modify All Data` permission which applies to all objects

Comment: @cropredy The label for it used to be Modify All Data at some point, I think. It may have changed since 2016, or maybe I did have a mistake. Either way, I'll update it to the modern terminology.